# Getting error when trying to fetch password from input box

Tags: java, jpasswordfield

doing some school coursework and currently creating a basic login system that will store usernames and passwords in a text file. I am new to java and found an old tutorial on making a similar system. everything works so far including the program being able to fetch the username from the input but any time i try the password as well i ge a whole host of errors. I have searched for the best part of half  an hour and cant seem to find relevant information so was just wondering if anyone could help or link me to a post or website that covers what i need (for context i am currently trying to get it to pring the username and password to the terminal just to test that it can fetch them properly)

code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {
    
    private static JLabel userLabel;
    private static JTextField userText;
    private static JLabel passwordLabel;
    private static JPasswordField passwordText;
    private static JButton button;
    private static JLabel success;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(panel);
     
        panel.setLayout(null);
        
        userLabel = new JLabel("User");
        userLabel.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25);
        panel.add(userLabel);
        userText = new JTextField(20);
        userText.setBounds(100, 20, 165 ,25);
        panel.add(userText);
        
        passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 50, 80, 25);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);
        JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField();
        passwordText.setBounds(100, 50, 165, 25);
        panel.add(passwordText);
        
        button = new JButton("Login");
        button.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        button.addActionListener(new GUI());
        panel.add(button);
        
        success = new JLabel("");
        success.setBounds(10, 110, 300, 25);
        panel.add(success);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String user = userText.getText();
        String passwordString = String.valueOf(passwordText.getPassword());
        System.out.println(user + ", " + passwordString);
        System.out.println(user);
    } 

}
```

error (after clicking the button):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JPasswordField.getPassword()" because "GUI.passwordText" is null
    at GUI.actionPerformed(GUI.java:57)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6614)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6379)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2769)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: What do you think the line `JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField();` does?  Hint: it does **NOT** set the value of the `GUI.passwordText` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField();
passwordText.setBounds(100, 50, 165, 25);
panel.add(passwordText);
```

You're re-declaring `passwordText`. That way you're obscuring the `passwordText` class variable, and never initializing it, so when you refer to it in your `actionPerformed` method a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

Just remove the re-declaration, i.e.

```
passwordText = new JPasswordField();
passwordText.setBounds(100, 50, 165, 25);
panel.add(passwordText);
```